# Sum of areas of $FCD$ and $FEB$

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, contest-math, circles

Consider the circle of radius $1$ with center at $A$ below with $\angle AFD=45^{\circ}$. Find the sum of the areas of $FCD$ and $FEB$

[image]

My try:

We have area of sector $ACD$ as $$ar(ACD)=\frac{\alpha}{2}$$

Area of sector $BAE$ as $$ar(BAE)=\frac{\beta}{2}$$

Area of triangle $AFD$ is:
$$ar(\Delta AFD)=\frac{AF\times \sin \alpha}{2}$$

Area of triangle $AFE$ is:
$$ar(\Delta AFE)=\frac{AF\times \sin \beta}{2}$$

So $$ar(FCD)+ar(FBE)=\frac{\alpha+\beta}{2}+\frac{AF(\sin \alpha-\sin \beta)}{2} $$

Also $\alpha+\beta=\frac{\pi}{2}, \alpha-\beta=2t$

Also $\sin \alpha-\sin \beta=2 \cos \left(\frac{\alpha+\beta}{2}\right) \sin\left(\frac{\alpha-\beta}{2}\right)=\sqrt{2}\sin t$

I am stuck here? Is it possible to find length of $AF$?

Comment: Are $\alpha,\beta$ known? Since I think the answer is depending on $\alpha$ amd $\beta$ actually...

Comment: If there are no other requirements to point $F$, you can place it on the circle and see that the sum of areas will be $1$

Comment: The result depends on the position of $F$.